# Creating a 'Ajaxified' Form Field Type

Tags: ajax, symfony, symfony-forms

In my application I've got a couple of form fields with many options. The problem I experienced is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469536/symfony2-how-to-create-a-form-field-of-type-entity-without-values): getting and parsing all options at every page load is expensive (Twig renders all options over and over again while no client side caching possible). That problem made me create a way to send the options via AJAX to the browser. Fairly simple approach:

1. Get all options (key-value) via AJAX (for example by getting /countries.json) and cache if possible. (in this case it's not very likely country names change very often)
2. Use selectize, select2 or a similar plugin to insert the options into the DOM.
3. Enjoy a faster Form :-)

To prevent Symfony from querying all options (not necessary: they're loading via AJAX) I added `setMaxResults(0)` to the `QueryBuilder` when the form is loaded (by adding an option via the controller). Yes, that's kludge. When submitting a form it will still perform a query, because it has to verify if the selected option exists (and check for Constraints).

I would like to create a [custom Form Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) that adds this functionality to the current `EntityType`: don't load the options while rendering the form, but still check if the selected option exists. I found [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321771/symfony2-change-choices-with-ajax-and-validation) [examples](http://showmethecode.es/php/symfony/symfony2-4-dependent-forms/) related to [dynamically modifying a form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html), but I haven't found examples related to modifying just one form field, independently of it's parent form.

How do I create a form field type like this? What's a good starting point? Extend `EntityType`, `ChoiceType` or an other approach?

I'm already using Symfony 3.1, so using [lazy loading of form choices](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-lazy-loading-of-form-choices) (New in Symfony 3.2) won't be a problem. Not sure if this new feature is related to my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending EntityType to allow extra choices set with AJAX calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178424/extending-entitytype-to-allow-extra-choices-set-with-ajax-calls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a bundle ([Alsatian/FormBundle](https://github.com/Alsatian67/FormBundle)), which does what you want on the server side.

- [How to avoid loading each entities by each form rendering](https://github.com/Alsatian67/FormBundle/blob/master/Form/AbstractExtensibleChoicesType.php) :

  ```
  abstract class AbstractExtensibleChoicesType extends AbstractRoutableType
  {
      public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
      {  
          $resolver->setDefault('choices',array());
      }
  }
  ```
- How to populate the form field with cached content :

That's your own logic, I would suggest : create a controller which only returns (as HTML) :

```
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
```

In the controller set Maxage :

```
/*
* @Route(...)
* @Cache(maxage=64000)
*/
public function getOptionsAction(Request $request) // Home
{
    $choices = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository //....

    return $this->render(/*...*/);
}
```

Use javascript to load this url and to put the html result in your select field.

If you are using something like Select2 :
Your Controller can also return the options as a JSONReponse(), then you can load this JSON directly from the select2 ajax option (see bundle documentation, that's how I use it).

- And the most difficult : [How to make the submitted choice valid](https://github.com/Alsatian67/FormBundle/blob/master/Form/Extensions/ExtensibleSubscriber.php) :

Get the sumitted choices in a Form::PRE_SUBMIT event (also PRE_SET_DATA if you use your form to edit), and reinject these choices to the field.

Answer (score 2):

Autocomplete with an Ajax controller option looks nice to me, but heres' another( maybe quicker?) option: render your form through hinclude.

[hinclude](http://mnot.github.io/hinclude/) is a JS library used to "defer" load of parts of a page, thought Ajax. Symfony comes with integrated support ([official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html)).

How yo use it:

- move your form render to another controller action, let's call it `formAction`
- include hinclude.js on your page (cf official Github)
- use this code to render your form:

  {{ render_hinclude(controller('...::form'), {'default': 'Loading...'}) }}
- you will probably want to keep your form handling in your original controller action, so modify the "action" of the generated form like this:

  $form = $this->createForm(new FormType(), $obj, array( 'action' => $this->generateUrl('original_form_action')));

Answer (score 1):

Considering your usecase, The best way would be to use an Autocomplete. Here is a [Symfony bundle](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXAutoCompleterBundle) I have been using and its awesome. I did some overwrite its javascript (autocompleter) to enhance few functionality as per my case.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I can use that bundle as inspiration. I don't want server side search handling, since client side searching is much faster. I don't like their controller implementation either, because it uses Twig to render a JSON output. Why?!

Comment: Yeah, Instead of using twig to render the json, I wrote in controller to return a `JsonResponse` of the result. No need to render a twig for json output.

Comment: I'm not sure such a bundle is usefull - just add Chosen library to your page + the init code, and here you do with a "normal" Entity type. Then indeed for the performance gain you have to go to the "Ajax" option, to load your entries.

Comment: I also find this bundle: https://github.com/Alsatian67/FormBundle. That looks exactly what I want.