# Symfony form EntityType without preloading

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

Is there a way to get an `EntityType` form element in Symfony, that doesn't preload all the entries, but still accepts them?

Background: It's for an image selector, where possibly 1000+ images will be stored. I don't want to put load on the DB, every time the field is rendered. The form has a custom frontend, using hidden fields an Javascript (to load a paged list of images).

The current implementation works, as it should, but as it extends the `EntityType` it does all the preloading, while when using a `ChoiceType` the form doesn't accept the values (unless, you give them as choices, which would mean to load all entries from the DB)

----------------------- EDIT -----------------------

I'm working with the suggested [bundle](https://github.com/Alsatian67/FormBundle). If you feel the need to have your own view (widget) as I do, you can achive that quite easy:

If you use composer, you can simple install all needed files running

`composer require alsatian/form-bundle dev-master`

With the bundle installed you can follow this steps:
First, you have to create your own form field (mine looks like this):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Fields;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Alsatian\FormBundle\Form\ExtensibleEntityType;


class UploadFileType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
    public function getParent() {
        return ExtensibleEntityType::class;
    }

    /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
    public function getName() {
        return 'app_upload_file';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_upload_file';
    }
}
```

Note: you can put anything you like in `getBlockPrefix`, just remember what you put there.

Next you need to modify your form theme ([doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#form-theming)) and add you own widget:

```
{%- block app_upload_file_widget -%}
    {{ dump(form) }}{# output some debug info #}
    {% if not expanded %}
        {# example for some fake entries #}
            {% if multiple %}
                <input type="hidden" name="{{ full_name }}" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="{{ full_name }}" value="2" />
                <input type="hidden" name="{{ full_name }}" value="3" />
            {% else %}
                <input type="hidden" name="{{ full_name }}" value="1" />
            {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        {{- block('choice_widget') -}}
    {% endif %}
{%- endblock app_upload_file_widget -%}
```

Note: Here we need our `getBlockPrefix` and just add a `_widget` to it!

Finally, we can add it to one of our forms:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Admin;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class CompanyType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('logo', \AppBundle\Form\Fields\UploadFileType::class, array(
                'class' => \AppBundle\Entity\File::class,
                'choice_label' => 'originalName',
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Company'
        ));
    }
}
```

Of course we need to have a join in our entity, for me, it looks something like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="File")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="logo_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $logo;
```

I hope, this helps someone, that is in the same situation as I am (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question comes every 3 days :)

I paste my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38576990/creating-a-ajaxified-form-field-type/38743873):

I wrote a bundle ([Alsatian/FormBundle](https://github.com/Alsatian67/FormBundle)), which does what you want on the server side.

- [How to avoid loading each entities by each form rendering](https://github.com/Alsatian67/FormBundle/blob/master/Form/AbstractExtensibleChoicesType.php) :

  ```
  abstract class AbstractExtensibleChoicesType extends AbstractRoutableType
  {
      public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
      {  
          $resolver->setDefault('choices',array());
      }
  }
  ```

  - And the most difficult : [How to make the submitted choice valid](https://github.com/Alsatian67/FormBundle/blob/master/Form/Extensions/ExtensibleSubscriber.php) :

Get the sumitted choices in a Form::PRE_SUBMIT event (also PRE_SET_DATA if you use your form to edit), and reinject these choices to the field.

Comment: Do I understand it right, I have to either use your bundle or I can stick with my own form field, in which I have to extend a `ChoiceType`. Initially the `ChoiceType` will have no choices set to it. In the `PPE_SUBMIT` event, I have to map the submitted ID's to Doctrine Entities. What I still don't understand, is how does Symfony accept the values as correct?

Comment: You can use my bundle or copy its logic ;). In PRE_SUBMIT, you have to ->add your entity type again and as 'choices' option, you set the submitted choices.

Comment: Where do I need to register the event, in my services? In your bundle it would be the `ExtensibleEntityType`, that I would have to extend, in order to get my own view/widget, right?

Comment: No you have to extend EntityType. (I created a new one ExtentedEntityType and I didn't change the widget). But the events must be on the parent form since you can only change a field by readding it to the parent. I put the events in a EventSubscriber applied on each FormTypes. But you can add a listener directly in your base form if you don't want to share it accross forms ...

Comment: If this question comes every 3 days I wonder why don't the symfony people do anything about it.